# Make terminal content fit the window size

Tags: terminal, fonts, terminal-emulator, enlightenment

I have a `fluxbox` environment that uses Eterm to open a telnet connection to my server.
I set Eterm to have the biggest fint possible, but it's not full-width. Is there a way to set Eterm to make the content fit the window size?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.  A clearer question would help.  Here are the possibilities.  The term *screen* refers to the computer's display, while *window* refers to the terminal emulator itself.

- Some terminal emulators can stretch their *window* to match the *screen* size.  But they draw their characters using a grid which may not evenly divide into the screen size.  If [`Eterm`](http://www.eterm.org/) used TrueType fonts, its developers *could* have provided for scaling the character-grid to more closely approximate the screen's limits.  But it uses bitmap-fonts, which cannot be adjusted so easily.
- In switching to full-screen, some terminal emulators do not necessarily "see" the full size.  You can work around that using [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html),  which determines the window's actual size and tells the shell about it.

Comment: Did you mean *window* instead of *screen* in the last sentence of the first paragraph?

Comment: Thanks for the advises and the explaination. I think I know better this issue. I'm going to find a way to use True Type Fonts.